# unable to extract devanagari from XeLaTeX generated PDF using ebook-convert

Tags: xetex, copy-paste, indic

I'm using TeXLive 2020 in Debian Bullseye. I generated a PDF document using XeLaTeX containing Devanagari characters. By using the option `\XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1`, I'm able to copy the Devanagari text from the XeLaTeX generated PDF into an Unicode-aware text editor.

But when I use `ebook-convert` to convert it into a plain text file using

`ebook-convert test.pdf test.txt`

I'm unable to get the original Devanagari characters back.

**edit:** The modified MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} %supports Unicode; compulsory
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Basic} %Unicode English font; any other font can be used as well. 
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily{\dev}[Script=Devanagari, Mapping=RomDev]{Shobhika}

\begin{document}
\XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1

    \textit{Plain Unicode Diacritical Text:} dhṛtarāṣṭra uvāca \\ 
    \textit{Plain Unicode Devanagari text:} {\dev धृतराष्ट्र उवाच} \\ 
    \textit{Devanagari text generated from RomDev.tec:} {\dev dhṛtarāṣṭra uvāca}
    
\end{document}
```

I have many XeLaTeX generated PDFs containing Devanagari characters, and I want to convert them into plain text documents (using the CLI and not Copy-Paste) for further usage, but am unable to do so. Please help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add `\documentclass{article}` to your fragment and run through xelatex, then the `pdftotext` utility (which is available in debian. although I'm using cygwin here) produces the following text file which is I think OK (although I can't read the text so I hope this is not missing anything)

```
ŚB 1.8.18
किमकुर्वत सञ्जय

1
```

The control character at the end is control-L at the page break.

so the command sequence is simply

`xelatex myfile`

`pdftotext myfile.pdf`

leaving `myfile.txt` with a plain text version.

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle!! The trick was to use ```pdftotext``` rather than ```ebook-convert```. And it also works for mapped Devanagari characters using ```RomDev.tec``` (from: https://github.com/somadeva/RomDev)